# How do I decrease the border width of the text form field?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

[image]

I need to reduce the width of my border side in TextField. How can I do that?

```dart
final emailNameField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: emailEditingController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: (email) => email != null && !EmailValidator.validate(email)
          ? "Enter a valid Email"
          : null,
      onSaved: (email) {
        emailEditingController.text = '$email';
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
          prefixIconColor: Colors.red,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(),
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1)),
          hintText: 'Email '),
    );

    //password field
    final passwordNameField = TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        controller: passwordEditingController,
        obscureText: true,
        onSaved: (value) {
          passwordEditingController.text = 'value';
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 15, 20, 15),
            prefixIconColor: Colors.red,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    width: 2, color: Color.fromARGB(26, 204, 32, 32))),
            hintText: 'Password ',
            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye_rounded)));
```

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: Are you using `Card` as top level widget?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap parent `Card` widget padding or just use `margin` property for outside spacing, and wrap `Column` widget with padding to provide inner spacing.

```dart
Card(
  //for out side or wrap with padding widget
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), 
  color: Colors.cyanAccent,

  // for inner spaciing
  child: Padding(
    // replace 16 with your desire padding value
    // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    padding:
        EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextField(),
        //...
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

More about [`Padding`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) and [`Card`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that through `decoration` property, here is a sample.
Pay attention that there is more than one type of borders styling you can apply.

- the docs are very clear and straight to the point in explaining that
  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html

  ```
   decoration: InputDecoration(                
                border: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 223, 223, 223), width: 1.5),
                ),
  ```